# Do While Loop in With clause: vba run-time error 91 - With Block Variable not Set

Tags: excel, vba

I want to match information from two sheets. However, I have to find the information in one sheet and the location to copy it in the other. Therefore, I do not know either location.

By executing the code below I get the following error:

```
Run time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

The error is throwed on the line with the loop condition

```
Loop While tmpVal2 < d.Row
```

Code:

```
Dim PO_Nr As Variant
Dim DB As Worksheet
Dim OutSht As Worksheet
Dim StartCellDB As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

Set OutSht = Worksheets("GUI")
Set DB = Worksheets("Datenbank")
Set StartCellDB = DB.Range("A2")

'Get Data from Database
LastRow = DB.Cells(DB.Rows.Count, StartCellDB.Column).End(xlUp).Row
PO_Nr = Sheets("GUI").Range("D5").Value

With DB.Range(StartCellDB, DB.Cells(LastRow, 1))
    'Find entry in "Datenbank"
    Set d = .Find(PO_Nr, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
        Do
            LastRow2 = OutSht.Cells(OutSht.Rows.Count, _
                OutSht.Range("A11").Column).End(xlUp).Row
            Set myRange = OutSht.Range(OutSht.Range("A12"), _
                OutSht.Range("A" & LastRow2)).Find(DB.Range _
                ("B" & d.Row).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
                OutSht.Range("B" & myRange.Row).Value = _
                    DB.Range("C" & d.Row).Value
            End If
            tmpVal2 = d.Row
            Set d = .FindNext(d)
        Loop While tmpVal2 < d.Row
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of those two things when it errors?

Comment: How is `d` declared?

Comment: And, as always **`Option Explicit`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set d = .FindNext(d)` is within the body of `If Not d Is Nothing Then`. Because you tested for `d` being `Nothing`, the `d` on the right hand side of the assignment won't be nothing -- but you are setting `d` to something else on the left hand side. Thus in the very next line of code, `Loop While tmpVal2 < d.Row`, `d` is no longer guaranteed to be not nothing. You could fix it with:

```
Dim dRow As Long 'at top of sub...

If Not d Is Nothing Then dRow = d.Row
Loop While Not d Is Nothing And tmpVal2 < dRow
```

The verbosity is needed since VBA lacks short-circuiting in its Boolean Operators.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks